# Passing the Values of Form Controls to an ASP.NET Page Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I have this function:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string EditPage(string nodeID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.conString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("contentPageGetDetail", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Global.SafeSqlLiteral(nodeID, 1);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }


   return nodeID;
}
```

I want to grab variables such as:

`<asp:HiddenField ID="hfNodeID" runat="server" />`

or

`<asp:RadioButtonList id="rblContentTypesGetAll" OnLoad="rblContentTypesGetAll_Load"  runat="server" >
 </asp:RadioButtonList>`

in my Web Form but When I try to reference their IDs they don't auto complete and can't be found. What am I missing? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebMethod is static - it will not have access to the form controls.  They're not executed in the context of the page - you'll need to get the required values using client side scripting and pass them in.

Comment: i've expanded your answer a little as it was almost what i was going to answer. Feel free to alter or rollback as you see fit.

Comment: I have all the values from jquery i need to hit the stored procedure. I need to take what i get from the stored procedure and populate the form with them

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript for retrieving values from HiddenField, RadioButtonList and pass them as parameters into EditPage method.

Comment: jQuery, or JavaScript in general. However you're calling the web method now, get the field values in your client-side code, then pass them as parameters to the method.

Comment: I am passing the value that I want and using that to get the details through a stored procedure but now I want to populate a form but can't without doing something with the returned values